# Lock Statement C# - Console.SetCursorPositon

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I want to create a programm which simultaneously move two players. The problem is that i dont know how to prevent each player to show their symbol at the others location.

Code:

```
class Player
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    private char symbol;
    private object Object = new object();
    public Player(char symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;            
    }

    public void Move(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Random))
            throw new Exception("Object isnt Random instance");
        Random rnd = obj as Random;

        X = rnd.Next(50);
        Y = rnd.Next(50);

        while (true)
        {
            int xChange = 0, yChange = 0;

            if (rnd.Next(100) < 50)
                xChange = rnd.Next(-1, 2);
            else
                yChange = rnd.Next(-1, 2);

            if (X + xChange < 0 || X + xChange > Console.BufferWidth || Y + 
            yChange < 0 || Y + yChange > Console.BufferHeight)
                continue;

            lock (Object)//critical section
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(X + xChange, Y + yChange);
                Console.Write(symbol);
            }

            X = X + xChange;
            Y = Y + yChange;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

class GameManager
{
    private List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
    private Dictionary<Player, Thread> threads = new Dictionary<Player, 
    Thread>();
    public static bool simulationStop = false;
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    public GameManager()
    {
        players.Add(new Player('O'));
        players.Add(new Player('X'));
    }

    public void Go()
    {
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        CreateThreads();

        while(simulationStop == false)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        //close all Threads at the end of the simulation
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Player, Thread> pair in threads)
        {
            threads[pair.Key].Abort();
        }
    }

    private void CreateThreads()
    {
        foreach(Player p in players)
        {
            threads.Add(p, new Thread(new 
            ParameterizedThreadStart(p.Move)));

            threads[p].Start(rnd);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the lock statement to prevent the threads entering the critical section at the same time, but it doesn´t work for some reason...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each player is locking on their own lock - so if you've got one thread per player, they will both be able to get into that section at the same time. Not that I'm sure threading is the best approach here, particularly as you're aborting threads...

Comment: Multithreading and Consoles do not mix. If you had any GUI technology I would also point out that those and Games do not mix well either. You use console, wich mixes even less well. Honestly it sounds like you ar eusing Multithreading and locking for something like a turnbased, hotseat multiplayer game, wich could be the most backwards way to go about it too.